# ReGex for 2 or more consecutive letters/numbers

Tags: javascript, php, regex, validation

I am trying to complete a regex where:

1. only 2 consecutive white spaces/hyphens/commas/dots/slashes are allowed.
2. maximum of 5 digits (consecutive or non-consecutive ) are allowed.
3. 3 or more consecutive letters are not allowed.

I have tried the below regex, it worked well for the first 2 points, still need to achieve the third point.

```
^(?=.{3,50}$)(?!.*(((\d{6}))|( {2})|(-{2})|(,{2})|(\.{2})|(\/{2})))([a-zA-Z0-9 \-,.\/])+$
```

I am using this regex to validate the address input from the user, I will be glad to modify it if there are any improvements or suggestions.

`Time Square, Main Road, 2279` **allowed**

`Time-Square, Main Road-2279` **allowed**

`Time  Square  Main Road` **NOT allowed** "double spaces"

`Time Square, Main Road, 22798741313` **NOT allowed**

`Time Square, Main Road..` **NOT allowed**

`Time Square, Main Road//` **NOT allowed**

`Time Square Main Road,,` **NOT allowed**

`Time Square Main Road--` **NOT allowed**

`-------` **NOT allowed**

`--//` **NOT allowed**

`--/` **NOT allowed**

`ttttttttttttttttttttttttttt` **NOT allowed**

`-/-` **NOT allowed**

`-/-` **NOT allowed**

`.,.`  **NOT allowed**

`,-,`  **NOT allowed**

`/-/-/-/-` **NOT allowed**

Comment: Do you mean `abc` is not allowed, or `aaa` is not allowed? Also is `--/` illegal or only `---`?

Comment: @Nick **aaa** is not allowed, both **--/** and **---** must be illegal.

Comment: *"3 or more consecutive letters are not allowed."*: but you give examples that are allowed that have 3 or more consecutive letters? Doesn't "Time" have 3 or more consecutive letters?

Comment: *"only 2 consecutive white spaces/hyphens/commas/dots/slashes are allowed."*: then by which rule should a double space be rejected? This rule seems to explicitly **allow** for it.

Comment: I think OP actually wanted 2 consecutive white spaces not allowed but wrote incorrect requirement in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this regex with negative lookahead conditions:

```bash
^(?!.*  )(?!.*[-,/.]{2})(?!.*(?:[^\d\n]*\d){6})(?!.*([a-zA-Z])\1\1).{3,50}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DwSQJi/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!.*  )`: Don't allow 2 consecutive spaces
- `(?!.*[-,/.]{2})`: Don't allow repeat of these special characters
- `(?!.*(?:[^\d\n]*\d){6})`: Don't allow more than 5 digits
- `(?!.*([a-zA-Z])\1\1)`: Don't allow 3 consecutive repeat of same letter
- `.{3,50}`: Match 3 to 50 of any characters
- `$`: End